What is the correct way to register a C++ enum so that the values are correct in QML?
I have the following enum declared as a Q_GADGET:
capture.hpp
#pragma once

#include <QObject>

class CaptureModeClass
{
  Q_GADGET
public:
  enum class Value
  {
    Screenshot = 0x1,
    Record     = 0x2,
    Stream     = 0x4
  };
  Q_ENUM(Value)

private:
  explicit CaptureModeClass() = default;
};
using CaptureMode = CaptureModeClass::Value;

I registered it in my main function using the following:
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<CaptureModeClass>(
  "smv.app.capture", 1, 0, "CaptureMode", "Not creatable as it is an enum");
qRegisterMetaType<CaptureMode>("CaptureMode");

The problem is that when this enum is used in a signal, in QML, I get a random value. For example, given the following signal in C++:
void mediaCaptureStarted(CaptureMode);

And a listener in QML:
function onMediaCaptureStarted(mode: int) {
  console.log("Media capture started:", mode);
}

When the signal is emitted: emit mediaCaptureStarted(CaptureMode::Screenshot);, in QML, I get something random like: Media capture started: 16711681.
And the value changes every time I recompile. Sometimes I get 1, but it is never consistent. Can someone point me to what I may be missing?
Thanks.

Your class should be inherrited from QObject...

@GAVD Wow that seemed to have solved it. I was following a guide here

@GAVD, you're wrong. Q_GADGET is designed just for those cases when the class is not inherited from QObject
